# Samba 4.2.3 - Access Denied to Home folder as root user

Tags: windows-7, linux, permissions, centos, samba

I am running CentOS 7.2 x64 with Samba 4.2.3-12.el7_2. My Samba config is as follows:

```
[global]
        server string =
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        guest ok = yes
        security = user
        map to guest = Bad Password

[root]
        browseable = no
        writeable = yes
        valid users = root
        path = /
```

I have run `smbpasswd -a root` and specified a password.

Finally I have restarted Samba using `service smb restart`.

In Windows 7, under Control Panel > User Accounts > Manage your credentials, I have added an entry using the server's hostname; the username is `<hostname>\root` and password is the password I used with smbpasswd.

In Windows Explorer, I am able to navigate to `<hostname>\root` and see the `/` partition with all the files and folders listed. However as soon as I double-click into `home`, Windows says I do not have permission.

Nothing is appearing in the log file under `/var/log/samba/log.smbd` other than the usual entries when the service is started.

Using the exact same configuration on my old CentOS 6.7 x64 server running Samba 4.0.0-66.el6_6.rc4 works fine and I can open the home folder via Windows Explorer no problem.

Any idea why it's not working with the new OS/Samba?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by adding `unix extensions = no` to [global] and `wide links = yes` to [root].